# Bootstrapped p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, bootstrap, resampling

I have a p-value that I generate via resampling.

**Resamples = 5000**

**Positive findings = 1000 positive findings**

**P-value = 1000/5000 = 0.2**

How can I compute the 95% confidence interval for this p-value?

I would assume it's a function of the number of positive findings and resamples 1000 and 5000 in this case, respectively.

Is the answer **p-value +- 1.96*sqrt(1000/5000 * (1 - 1000/5000) / 1000)**?

Why this matters: Resampling is very expensive in my code and I'd like to stop resampling as soon as the 95% confidence interval for the boostrapped p-value doesn't include 0.05. Right now I'm doing a million resamplings to estimate every p-value and it is very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to minimize the number of samples, you are probably better off by estimating the $p$-value using (# positives + 1) / (# resamples + 1), see: (Davison and Hinkley 1997, chapter 4). In that case you can get a fine estimate of the Monte Carlo confidence interval using the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles from the beta distribution with parameters # positives + 1, and # resamples + 1 - # positives. I discussed the logic behind using the beta distribution on pages 9 and 10 of [this](http://www.maartenbuis.nl/presentations/gsug13.pdf) presentation.

Davison, A.C. and D.V. Hinkley (1997). *Bootstrap methods and their application*. Cambridge university press.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you mean to say that the parameters for the beta distribution are #positives + 1 and #negatives + 1? The beta distribution using these parameters has a mean that very closely matches the bootstrapped p-value

Comment: The mean of that beta distribution is the estimate of the $p$-value I gave above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Using my example above, the and qbeta being my quantile function: lower bound = qbeta(0.025, 1001, 5001-1000) will give me the lower bound for a 95% confidence interval.Thanks for your help and thank you for providing references for me to review. I appreciate your help. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to get a citation for using the beta distribution to minimize the number of samples. Do you have such a source? It sounds like the book you cited will serve as a reference for estimating the p-value using (# positives + 1) / (# resamples + 1) alone, but not for using the beta distribution.

Comment: I have added a link to a presentation where I explained the logic behind it. I could not find another reference.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. This is very useful. Ideally, a reference would be used to justify it to reviewers as I'd like to include this in a publication to justify fewer resamples than is typical. I can guarantee you many people aren't familiar with this approach and it would save a lot of processing time. I see many publications with a fixed number of computationally expensive resamples

Comment: It is probably easier to explain the sampling distribution of the proportion of positive findings: That is just the binomial distribution. That is so trivial that I don't think you need a reference for that. With that you can create your Monte Carlo confidence interval by using the .025th and .975th percentiles fo the binomial distribution. A very respectable reference for using the proporiton as an estimate for the $p$-value is chapter 16 of Efron, B., & Tibshirani, R. (1993). *An introduction to the bootstrap*. CRC press.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I know the binomial distribution is used in this way, but using the beta distribution after smoothing is new to me.